# How to get the result in single row when using sub queries in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I am trying to get a table with stage_name and its count in respective loan product. Like in below example stage_name is RCO and there are three loan product, Auto loan, Consumer loan and Credit card. Though I have used the logic and getting the right output, but in the output, I am getting the separate row for each stage_name and loan product case. I want only one row with all the three result. Please look at my code below, actual output and desired output:

```
SELECT 
    'RCO',
    CASE 
       WHEN sq2.loan_type = 'Consumer loan' 
          THEN SUM(ISNULL(sq2.user_count, 0)) 
    END AS Consumer_Loan,
    CASE 
       WHEN sq2.loan_type = 'Auto Loan' 
          THEN SUM(ISNULL(sq2.user_count, 0))  
    END AS Auto_Loan,
    CASE 
       WHEN sq2.loan_type = 'Credit Card' 
          THEN SUM(ISNULL(sq2.user_count, 0)) 
    END AS Credit_Card
FROM
    (SELECT 
         'RC0' AS ws_name, 'Consumer loan' AS loan_type,
         COUNT(DISTINCT a.bpm_referenceno) AS user_count, 
         a.takenby AS user_id
     FROM
         BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm a
     INNER JOIN
         (SELECT 
              m.bpm_referenceno
          FROM 
              BM_RLOS_EXTTABLE m
          WHERE 
              m.loan_type = 'Consumer Loan') sq1 ON a.bpm_referenceno = sq1.bpm_referenceno
    WHERE 
        a.winame='RCO'
    GROUP BY 
        a.takenby

UNION
SELECT 'RC0','Auto loan',
count (DISTINCT a.bpm_referenceno), a.takenby
from
BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
m.bpm_referenceno
FROM BM_RLOS_EXTTABLE m
WHERE m.loan_type='Auto Loan')sq1
ON a.bpm_referenceno = sq1.bpm_referenceno
WHERE a.winame='RCO'
GROUP BY a.takenby

UNION
SELECT 'RC0','Credit Card',
count (DISTINCT a.bpm_referenceno), a.takenby
from
BM_RLOS_DecisionHistoryForm a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
m.bpm_referenceno
FROM BM_RLOS_EXTTABLE m
WHERE m.loan_type='Credit Card')sq1
ON a.bpm_referenceno = sq1.bpm_referenceno
WHERE a.winame='RCO'
GROUP BY a.takenby) sq2
GROUP BY sq2.ws_name,sq2.loan_type
```

Actual output:

```
    |--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
    |   Stg_nm     |   Cons_ln   |   Auto_lan  | Credit_card |
    |--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
    |    RCO       |     NULL    |     NULL    |     8       |
    |--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
    |    RCO       |     NULL    |     55      |     NULL    |
    |--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
    |    RCO       |      81     |     NULL    |     NULL    |
    |--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
```

Required Output

```
|--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|      Stg_nm  |     Cons_ln |   Auto_lan  | Credit_card |
|--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|    RCO       |     81      |     55      |     8       |
|--------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
```

Comment: First understand the difference between `UNION ALL` not `UNION` - You probably want `UNION ALL`. In answer to your question, you need to wrap that whole thing in another set of `SUM()`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid.. you mean to put all the above query in sub query and then fetch the sum from the sub query?

Comment: Yep. I'll post an answer

Comment: Now that your query has been edited... no. Let me post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top half should be like this - reverse the usage of `SUM` and `CASE`, and remove the last `GROUP BY` altogether

```
SELECT 
    'RCO',
    SUM(CASE 
          WHEN sq2.loan_type = 'Consumer loan' 
          THEN sq2.user_count 
          ELSE 0 END
        ) 
    AS Consumer_Loan,
    SUM(CASE 
          WHEN sq2.loan_type = 'Auto loan' 
          THEN sq2.user_count 
          ELSE 0 END
        ) 
    AS Auto_Loan,
    SUM(CASE 
          WHEN sq2.loan_type = 'Credit Card' 
          THEN sq2.user_count 
          ELSE 0 END
        ) 
    AS Credit_Card
FROM
<your existing query, with the final GROUP BY removed>
```

But you need to remove the `GROUP BY` from the end altogether

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't solved the issue, it just swapped the NULL value with 0. Nothing else. Also in your query you are using two END keyword after each CASE statement which is causing error. I just want all the result in single row.

Comment: I'll edit the answer. You also need to change your group by